# 2D rotation to 3D with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to recreate a functionality of a snippet I found that rotates any given element around another element, very much like a planetary rotation.
I want to use this 2D rotation system for a 3D project with three.js.

The 2D functionality is in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL2vzopz/).

I'm having trouble implementing it in [my own scene](http://jsfiddle.net/SF9tX/434/) though. For starters, getting the elements' id's for meshes in three.js is tricky.

```
myObject.name = "objectName";
...
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );
```

This example code where you name your meshes and pass it through isn't doing it for me - which marks the only search result I could find.

Also, I don't understand that by adding the third dimension how the trigonometric function would need to be written.

```
return {
        x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX, 
        y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY 
    };
```

So there's some work involved that's simply beyond me. That's why I don't see how the functionality needs to look like for a 3D environment? Thank you if you can help me out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you had trouble implementing it because you could almost copy paste from the snippet you found.

I don't know how to use JSFiddle. I clicked update but I have no idea if you can see the changes. That's why I'll post them here as well.

```
//creates the scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 500 / 400, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xffffff, 1 );
renderer.setSize(625, 500);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//creates the two objects
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.5, 50, 50);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x9a806e} );
var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
//sets positions
sphere1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
sphere2.position.set(-10, 0, 0);

//adds the two spheres to the scene
scene.add(sphere1);
scene.add(sphere2);

//default camera pos
camera.position.z = 400;

var object = {speed: 1.2, spin: 100, side: 0.0};

// copied from snippet
function rotation(coorX, coorY, object) {
object.side +=  (1.0 / object.speed); 
var ang = object.side * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; 
var r = object.spin;

return {
    x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX, 
    y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY 
};
}  

//renders the scene
var render = function () {
    newpos = rotation(sphere1.position.x, sphere1.position.y, object);
  sphere2.position.x = newpos.x;
    sphere2.position.y = newpos.y;
renderer.render(scene, camera);    
};

setInterval(render, 1000 / 60)
```

I also think you can use this in 3d as well. Because 3d only adds the z-axis and I think that makes no difference. But maybe you can explain me your concerns about using it in 3d.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. I don't know why it threw an error when I tried to implement that code, but you left it almost untouched and it works. I don't know the answer to that. But I still need to see how I can add the z-axis in the rotation. I will work on that and come back later with the answer.

Comment: I had to play around with the trigonometric function but that ultimately got resolved.  The return value had to look like this in order for it to work.

return {
    x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX, 
    y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY,
    z: Math.tan(ang) / r - Math.cos(ang) * r - coorZ
};
The y axis is obsolete but for the rest, this rotates the elements in ellipses the way I wanted it.

Comment: You should google "euler angles" "quaternions" and even "rotations in 3D". Code wise this is all relatively straight forward, as far as three js is concerned there might be questions about ordering matrices and components and stuff. Otherwise this might be better suited for math stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that lets three.js handle trigonometry for you: http://jsfiddle.net/SF9tX/438/

relevant code:

```
var sphere2Rig = new THREE.Object3D();

sphere2.position.x = -10;
sphere2Rig.add(sphere2);
scene.add(sphere2Rig);

var render = function () {
    sphere2Rig.rotation.z -= 0.025;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
```

So you create a "rig" that is positioned at the origin and contains the `sphere2`-object positioned somewhere else. Now if you rotate the rig, you automatically also rotate all children with it, using the rig's origin as center-point for rotation.

Comment: I'm not very used to jsfiddle either, but to my mind, that can't be all the code, right? Copying it and placing it inside another empty jsfiddle won't show anything run at all, so there's some voodoo in place here. I wish I knew how to implement it.

Comment: no, that's the few lines I added to the code you wrote. See here for the running example: http://jsfiddle.net/SF9tX/438/

Comment: oh wait, I might have misread your question. If you create a new one, you need to add three.js via external resources (using this URL for instance: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r81/three.js). I just forked OPs fiddle and edited it, no Idea how three.js was loaded there.

Comment: I guess it's loaded via the javascript-settings inside the JS-area: "Frameworks & Extensions"